# What's the measure of the $\angle ABC$ in the triangle below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference:

> In triangle $ABC$, the ratio of the squares of sides $AC$ and $AB$ is equal to the ratio of the projections of these sides
> on side $BC$. Calculate $\angle ABC$, if $\angle BCA = 80^\circ$ (Answer:$10^\circ$)

My progress:

I drew the picture but could not see the similarity with the given data.

Is it possible to determine similarity with this data alone, or is there a lack of data?

$\dfrac{AC^2}{AB^2} =\dfrac{m}{n}$

[image]

Comment: The data is sufficient. Please use Pythagoras to write $AC^2$ and $AB^2$ and equate to $m/n$, you will get the answer. If you get stuck. please post your progress.

Comment: It is also given $AD \perp BC$. You've missed this. This is what projection means.

Comment: @soupless No I am not assuming that; that is to be shown. I am just using the fact that $AD$ is perp to $BC$.

Comment: @MathLover  
Would it be correct as I demonstrated above?

Comment: @petaarantes yes it is correct

Comment: @petaarantes Your answer below shows that another solution is $m=n$, and $\triangle ABC$ may be isosceles with $AB=AC$.

Comment: @peterwhy  I don't understand...if m = n then $AD^2(n-m) = 0$ ????

Comment: @petaarantes Yes, and cancelling $(n-m)$ would be illegal.

Comment: @peterwhy but you say tha m=n is another solution...if m=n  then n- m = 0 what can't happen...could you clarify your consideration?

Comment: @petaarantes You could divide both sides by $(n-m)$ because you assumed it is non-zero, and that gives $AD^2=mn$. The other case you didn’t consider is when $(n-m)=0$, and you can’t divide by zero. This case leads to an isosceles $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: @peterwhy   strange...by geogebra, f the triangle is isosceles with the base angles equal to $80^o$ we will have $\frac{m}{n}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{AC^2}{AB^2}$

Comment: @petaarantes Are you sure? My first comment already clarified that $AB=AC$. $B,C$ are the base vertices and $A$ is the apex vertex. The altitude $AD$ would bisect $BC$. Both ratios are equal to $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a hint from Math:

$\dfrac{AC^2}{AB^2} =\dfrac{m}{n}$

$AD \perp BC \implies \\
\triangle ABD: AB^2 = AD^2+n^2\\
\triangle ACD: AC^2=AD^2+m^2\\
\frac{AD^2+m^2}{AD^2+n^2}=\frac{m}{n}\rightarrow nAD^2+nm^2=mAD^2+mn^2\rightarrow \\AD^2(n-m)=mn(n-m)\implies AD^2 = mn$

Therefore we have a metric relation of the right triangle and therefore $\angle A = 90^o$ and $\angle B = 10^o$